# error #1698 phpmyadmin "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'"

Tags: phpmyadmin

Acabo de instalar todo el paquete Apache junto con PHP y phpMyAdmin. El problema es que cuando trato de iniciar sesión me da este error:

> #1698  Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

y

> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1698): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

¿Qué debo hacer?

Comment: te hace falta información dice yes o no en la parte del password?

Comment: sigue este hilo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281594/error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Hay una pregunta similar en SO versión Inglés. Seguramente te va a ayudar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645309/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost

Comment: Lo instalaste con algun software como xampp, lampp, wampp u otro similar?

Comment: reinstale todo... estoy trabajando en lubuntu

Comment: voy a tratar de seguir los pasos que me pasaron... gracias

Comment: la verdad veo que hay muchas opciones y no se cual hacer, no quiero lios... je

Comment: noto que no tengo instalado mysql-server... eso puede afectar? tengo instalado MariaDB y phpMyadmin

Comment: mariadb es por lo general equivalente a mysql, en el segundo link que te pasaron hay un par de pasos extra para mariadb (como especificar el nuevo password y como reiniciar el servicio)

Comment: gracias a todos... ya pude solucionarlo... leí todo bien y seguí los pasos, me había dado otro error y siguiendo los pasos los solucione. gracias

Answer (score 10):

Yo tenia el mismo inconveniente cuando instale `phpMyAdmin` después de formatear mi PC.

La solución es sencilla, si al momento de instalar tratas de iniciar sesión y te aparece el siguiente error:

> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1698): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Debes de abrir una terminal, en mi caso uso Linux pero también puedes en Windows, y debes crear nuevo usuario y darle permisos de la siguiente forma:

- Ingresa esta linea de código en la terminal:

  ```
  sudo mysql -p -u root
  ```
- Va solicitar el `password` del usuario `root`. En mi el caso no le ingrese nada.
- Seguido, ingresa esta linea en la terminal:

  ```
  CREATE USER 'newuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'you_password_here';
  ```

  El debe darte un resultado similar a este:

  > Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
- Luego ingresas la siguiente linea de código, que es para dar privilegios a este nuevo usuario:

  ```
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'newuser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
  ```

  Te dara una respuesta como esta:

  > Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
- Por último debes ejecutar:

  ```
  FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
  ```

Y listo.

Comment: Creando el usuario como indicáis funciona correctamente. Mil gracias
;-)

Comment: En mi caso no me sirvió el comando de GRANT ALL que usaste, tuve que usar el que @Alberto J dio en una respuesta más debajo

Answer (score 5):

```
$sudo mysql -u root<p>
[mysql] use mysql;<p>
[mysql] update user set plugin='' where User='root';<p>

[mysql] flush privileges;<p>
[mysql] \q
```

Comment: Para que tu respuesta sea mejor recibida por la comunidad, editala y explica como llegaste a la solución. No olvides leer [answer]

Comment: Me sirvió perfectamente!!!

Answer (score 5):

me funciono mucho gracias.

Hice:

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'you_password_here';
```

y luego

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'newuser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

y Funciono!

Comment: Excelente me funciono solo con hacer lo que dice @Alberto J

Comment: Solo como nota, al otorgar `ALL PRIVILEGES` después del `GRANT` hay que tener en cuenta que el usuario de MySQL va poder hacer uso de `DML` y `DDL` sin limitaciones, lo cual en algún punto, podría ocasionar una falla de seguridad y una violación indirecta a la tríada de la `CIA`, por lo que hay que valorar siempre la opción de otorgar todos los privilegios o no. Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

aunque se que el tema está un poco viejo, quiero comentar algo sobre la solución que dió **Darwin Tusarma Taba Emprendeco** la cual es correcta. Y la cuestión es que desde hace agún tiempo el usuario *root* de mysql y mariadb requiere privilegios sudo o superusuario, phpmyadmin no puede usar credenciales de superusuario del sistema por lo que la solución mas viable es crear un usuario con los mismos privilegios que la cuenta root en el gestor de base de datos.

Comment: Ayudaría mucho a tu aporte, que colocaras una fuente donde se pueda consultar lo qye mencionas respecto a permisos

Comment: Hola, yo lo leí aquí. https://devanswers.co/phpmyadmin-access-denied-for-user-root-localhost/