# MySQL error al crear objeto en Java

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, raspbian

Estoy haciendo una prueba de conexiones con un archivo JSP a una base de datos desde una máquina virtual de Raspbian. En Windows me funciona perfectamente, pero en esta no.
Tengo diferentes salidas de texto en los catch dependiendo del try que esté realizando, en este caso el que me salta es en el siguiente:

```
try {
   BaseDatos bd = new BaseDatos();

   // POR AQUÍ ABAJO HAY MÁS CÓDIGO DE COSAS

} catch(Exception ex){
           out.println(ex);
           out.println(" || Crear base de datos");
}
```

Siendo el resultado de la ejecución el siguiente error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' || Conexion base de datos java.lang.NullPointerException || Crear base de datos
```

En la clase donde hago la conexión tengo los siguientes datos relacionados:

```
public class BaseDatos {

private String USUARIO = "root";
private String PASSWORD = "";
private String NOMBREBD = "prueba";
private String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/"+NOMBREBD + "?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8";
//private static final String DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:MKYONG";
private final static String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private Connection conn = null;
private Statement stmt = null;
private PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
String servidor = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
Connection conexionBD;
String cosa;

/**
 * Constructor vacio de la clase
 */
public BaseDatos () {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El error que muestra es porque los permisos que tienes para root, son como usuario local (**'root'@'localhost'**), no como usuario remoto (**'root'@'%'**).
Da permisos de acceso remoto a root de la siguiente forma:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'contraseña_de_root';
```

Tambien debes considerar si es conveniente dar permisos tan amplios en remoto al usuario root

El mismo tipo de error (**Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'**) ha sido comentado aquí: [error #1698 phpmyadmin “Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'”](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/161109/error-1698-phpmyadmin-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost)

Comment: Lo acabo de probar pero no. También he probado a crearme un usuario para gestionar los datos pero tampoco. Me sale el siguiente error:
 
```java.lang.NullPointerException || Crear base de datos```

Por lo que imagino que está intentando evaluar algo que tiene como resultado null, pero no se el qué. Me extraña mas que nada por que al crear el objeto no estoy haciendo nada, es un constructor vacío.

Comment: Entiendo que estas conectando en remoto a ese servidor virtual ¿Correcto? Si estoy en lo cierto, cambia tambien la cadena de conexión al servidor. Cambia "localhost" por la ip del servidor remoto

Comment: Lo he probado por si las moscas y no sirve. De todas formas donde estoy haciendo las pruebas es en un servidor tomcat desde la dirección "localhost:8080".

Answer (score 0):

al parecer el error era una tontería. Resulta que me estaba dando un error en una sección que llamaba aun método que usaba una información que estaba mal proporcionada y que di por echo que no iba a fallar.