# Failed to load phpMyAdmin configuration: syntax error, unexpected variable "$cfg" y access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysqli, phpmyadmin

Recién creé una base de datos desde PHPMyAdmin. Cerré la aplicación y al intentar volver a acceder no me deja, me marca este error:

> **Failed to load phpMyAdmin configuration (.\config.inc.php:24): syntax error, unexpected variable "$cfg"**

Igual cuando trato de conectarme a la db desde una pequeña página que estoy realizando me lanza este error:

> **Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\conexion.php on line 8**

De esto ya puse password al usuario root pero el error persiste.

Así quedó la configuración:

```
/* Authentication type and info */
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true
   $cfg['Lang'] = '';
```

¿Qué sucede?

Comment: Te falta un `;` después del `true`

Comment: @Marcos Agregue el ; me tira el error:
mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: ¿Sabes entrar por consola a `mysql?` [Más info](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/161109/16597)

Comment: @Marcos Si, se accesar por consola.

Comment: El usuario `root`, por defecto, sirve para acceder desde la consola/terminal. Si queres acceder por otra via, conviene crear OTRO usuario y darle permisos. Revisa el post que te pase en el comentario anterior.

Comment: @Marcos Gracias agregue otro usuario con full access. Pregunta resuelta.